# how to replace 'dollar' sign with another character used in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How will I change the dollar sign (alias for 'jquery') used in jquery with another character.
For example

```
$("#id").css("height","210px");
```

I want to change this to

```
*("#id").css("height","210px");
```

Answer (score 11):

You cannot change `$` to `*` because `*` is not a valid identifier. But you can change it to a valid one:

```
(function (foobar) {
    foobar("#whatever").css(....)


})(jQuery);
```

Given that [JavaScript identifiers are unicode, you can try fancy things](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9337047/96656) like for example:

```
(function (Ω) {
    Ω("#whatever").css(....)
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: +1 thanks. I thought it `* denotes All elements`.  But didn't verified. So posted a wrong answer.

Answer (score 7):

dont use `*` as a variable name please choose valid name  here i choose `js`

```
var js =jQuery.noConflict(); //by this you can do it
```

reference **[jQuery.noConflict()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)**

Answer (score 2):

jQuery comes with a [noConflict](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) command which you can assign to a custom variable:

```
var jq = jQuery.noConflict(true);
```

This means you can do regular jQuery with your symbol:

```
jq.css('height', '200px');
```

You cannot use the asterisk (*) because it is a reserved character.